# How to insert Current time in TIMESTAMP column(Oracle) from java class using jdbc

Tags: oracle, jdbc, timestamp

i have tryed many things but not able to insert data in my timestamp column.
from toad its possible using this

```
UPDATE SUPPORTSTAFF 
     SET SUPPSTAFFJOINDATE=to_timestamp('27/02/2002 15:51.12.539880', 'dd/mm/yyyy hh24:mi.ss.ff') 
 where JDBCUSERID='5700';
```

its working

but how can i insert data from java class using create statment and execute query its giving me invalid month error

Comment: Show us the Java code.

Comment: its done THanks a lot for fast responce .follwed jon's answer .now its working.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Use a `PreparedStatement` with a parameter for the timestamp, e.g.

```
UPDATE SUPPORTSTAFF SET SUPPSTAFFJOINDATE = ? where JDBCUSERID = ?
```

and then set the parameters:

```
statement.setTimestamp(1, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
statement.setString(2, "your ID");
```

(Then execute the statement, obviously.)

Comment: Thanks a lot Jon ..you saved my day. was trying from last 4 hour. this was my first question to stackoverflow which was answered in 1 min .awesome.. Just love it

Comment: Jon, what about Oracle DB ? I tried this on my oracle 11g and I get an ORA-01461: can bind a LONG value only for insert into a LONG column.

Comment: @GaëlOberson: That comment doesn't really give enough information - it's not clear where LONG comes into it at all. It sounds like it's worth asking a new question.

Comment: @Jon Not really. I have a TIMESTAMP COLUMN in my table, I use a preparded statement and set the column value like in your example, getting the oracle exception i mention.

Comment: @GaëlOberson: If you're using `setTimestamp`, it seems *very* odd that it's complaining about a LONG. I really *would* suggest opening a new question, as this is definitely unexpected behaviour. Ideally, create a new table and a program which *just* shows this problem - aside from anything else, that will help to validate that it's not just that you've used the wrong parameter number somewhere.

Comment: I have followed the same but still getting the exception "not a valid month"! here is the code snippet I have    updateStmt.setTimestamp(8, new Timestamp(System.currentTimeMillis()));
       updateStmt.executeUpdate();

Comment: @Telebh: I suggest you ask a new question with a [mcve]. That isn't enough information on its own.